# How to debug website for iPhone on Windows without having an iPhone?

Tags: ios, debugging

A client has reported that a website doesn't work on iPhones. As far as I can see on the screenshots, there's the skeleton but the content that should be loaded via AJAX is not present.

What can I do to find the cause without having an iPhone myself?

Maybe there's a service that allows me to run a debuggable iPhone browser somewhere in the cloud?

Comment: Have you tried using a xcode iPhone simulator browser??

Comment: I have not, should it work to simulate the iOS Chrome properly? I didn't try it because I'm not sure if it will help with the iPhone-specific problem and it seems that running those virtual MACs themselves is pretty expensive.

Comment: iPhone simulator can run only on a Mac and it comes with a safari browser and doesn't have a chrome.you can try this link for a online simulator http://www.appsimulator.net/apple-iphone-6.html

Comment: Thanks everyone for chiming in! This time I solved the problem using a different approach - sentry.io to send me the JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can try xcode iPhone simulator browser.iPhone simulator can run only on a Mac and it comes with a safari browser and doesn't have a chrome.you can try this link for a online simulator

http://www.appsimulator.net/apple-iphone-6.html

Comment: I don't think that last simulator does anything - it seems to simply put my site in a phone-sized iframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Appetize.io](https://appetize.io).

Free to use for 100 minutes per month per user.

Even in the demo section you can select different options of iPhones and try out the URL within 1 minute too. The site has been helpful for me.